# Trying to open a popup through bootstrap on clicking of hyperlink

Tags: c#, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to open a popup through bootstrap on clicking a hyperlink
This is the hyperlink where data is coming through database on clicking this a bootstrap popup should be opened.

```
<td id="statusdiv_@item.EscId" class="statusdiv">@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status).ToString(), "Escalation")</td>
```

Div which i want to open as pop up is `<div id="myModal" role="dialog">` 
This is the jquery through which i am trying to open it

```
$(".statusdiv").click(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.
complete c# code

```
@using iMBDian.Models;
@*@model List<iMBDian.Models.Escalation>*@
@model IEnumerable<iMBDian.Models.Escalation>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_EmployeeLayout.cshtml";
    string _vpth = Html.GetUrl("Escalation");
    Languages _owrpr = new Languages();
    _owrpr = (Languages)Session["objWrapper"];
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) { }
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Escalation", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "IssueForm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <div class="col-md-12 login-text">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Department
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlDepartment", new SelectList(ViewBag.Department, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName", ViewData["Dept"]), "-- " +
             HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Department", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString() + " --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Issue Type
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlIssueType", new SelectList(ViewBag.IssueType, "IssueId", "IssueType", ViewData["Issue"]), "-- Select Issue --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 login-text">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Employee
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlEmployee", new SelectList(ViewBag.Employee, "ErpCode", "Name", ViewData["Empl"]), "-- " +
             HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Employ", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString() + " --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Priority", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlPriority", new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "High" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Medium", Value = "Medium" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Low", Value = "Low" },
                     }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 login-text">
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "UploadFile", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    @Html.TextBox("fileUploader", "", new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Description", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo)
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    @Html.TextArea("txtDescription", "", new { @class = "form-control", rows = "3", placeholder = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Description", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo) })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 login-text">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.Hidden("FormType", "BindIssue")                    
                    <input type="submit" id="btnEscalation" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value='@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Submit", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()' />
                </div>
            </div>
            if (ViewBag.ConfMsg != null)
            {
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        alert('@ViewBag.ConfMsg');
                    });
                </script>
            }
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped rht-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h2><strong>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "TicketDetails", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</strong></h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bg-danger" style="background: #2d323e !important; border-radius: 10px;">

                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "CreatedBy", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "CreatedDate", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "IssueType", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "AssignedTo", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "ClosedBy", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "ClosedDate", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>

                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Description", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Status", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th style="padding:0px 10px;">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "TimeRemaining", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <p style="font-size:11px; margin-bottom: 5px;">HH:MM:SS</p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CreatedName)</td>
                        <td>@item.CreatedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.IssueType)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.AssignedPerson)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ClosedBy)</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (item.ClosedDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy") != "01 January 0001")
                            {
                                @Html.Raw(item.ClosedDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"))
                            }
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @if (item.CreatorDescription.Length > 10)
                            {
                                @Html.Raw(item.CreatorDescription.Substring(0, 10) + "...")
                            }
                            else
                            {@Html.Raw(item.CreatorDescription) }
                        </td>                       
                        <td id="statusdiv_@item.EscId" class="statusdiv">@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status).ToString(), "Escalation")</td>
                        @*<td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status) </td>*@
                        <td>
                            <div id="clockdiv_@item.EscId" class="clockdiv" tat="@item.CreatedDate.AddHours(item.TAT)">
                                <div style="display:inline-flex;">
                                    <span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

   @*6-feb-2017 start*@

    <div id="myModal" role="dialog">        
        <table  class="table table-striped rht-table top-tbl">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-danger">
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Zone", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("zone")</td>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Date", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Date")</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-danger">
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "CreatedBy", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("CreatedBy")</td>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "CreatedDate", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Date")</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-danger">
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "ClosedBy", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("ClosedBy")</td>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "ClosedDate", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("ClosedDate")</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-danger">
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Priority", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlPriority", new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Text = "Open", Value = "Open" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Close", Value = "Close" },
                     }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </td>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "IssueType", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("IssueType")</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-danger">
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "AssignedTo", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("AssignedTo")</td>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Branch", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Branch")</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-danger">
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Status", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlPriority", new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Text = "Open", Value = "Open" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Close", Value = "Close" },
                     }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </td>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "IssueDescription", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo)</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextArea("IssueDescription", "", new { @class = "form-control", rows = "3", placeholder = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Description", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo) })</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-danger">
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Forward", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlEmployee", new SelectList(ViewBag.Employee, "ErpCode", "Name", ViewData["Empl"]), "-- " +
             HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Forward", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString() + " --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </td>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Attachment", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Attachment", "", new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-danger">
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Remarks", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo)</th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextArea("txtDescription", "", new { @class = "form-control", rows = "3", placeholder = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Description", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo) })
                </td>
        </thead>
    </table>

    @*6-feb-2017 end*@
</div>
    </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#btnEscalation').click(function () {
            HideErrorMsg(); HideLblMsg();
            var _alrt1 = ""
            $('.form-control').each(function () {
                var _xkid = $(this).context.id.slice(3);
                if ($(this).val() == "" && _xkid != "eUploader" && _xkid != "Description") _alrt1 = 'Please Select ' + _xkid;
                if (_alrt1 != "") {
                    $(this).closest('div').append('<div class="error">' + _alrt1 + '</div>');
                    $(this).focus();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (_alrt1 == "") $('#FormType').val('SaveData');
        });
        $('#ddlDepartment').change(function () {
            $('.IssueForm').submit();
        })

    });
    //2feb - 2017_start
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }
    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        //var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
            //daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        }
        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse('2017/02/05'));
    $('.clockdiv').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id'), tat = $(this).attr('tat');
        initializeClock(id, tat);
    });
    //2feb - 2017_end
    //3feb - 2017_start
   // $('.statusdiv').each(function () {
    //$('.statusdiv').click(function () {
    $(".statusdiv").click(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
        //alert('hello');        
        //$('#myModal').dialog({
        //    height:700,
        //    width: 700,
        //    //modal:true,
        //});        
    //});
    //3feb - 2017_end
</script>
@*19jan-2017_End*@
```

Comment: Use: 
` $(".statusdiv").click(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal("toggle");
    });  
`

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasaliI tried but it's not working

Comment: remove ActionUrl part: Something like below
<td id="statusdiv_@item.EscId" class="statusdiv">Click Here</td>

Comment: It's working black screen is visible but popup is not opening or visible

Comment: doing these changes 1. <td id="statusdiv_@item.EscId" class="statusdiv"  data-target="#myModal"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status) </td>  2. <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> 3. $(".statusdiv").click(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal();
    }); It will work

Comment: but i want it should work with hyperlink  like this <td id="statusdiv_@item.EscId" class="statusdiv"  data-target="#myModal">@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status).ToString(), "Escalation") </td>  any idea would be appreciated.